# How to uniquely parameterize an array of interfaces?

Tags: parameters, system-verilog

I'm trying to give unique IDs to the interfaces in an array that I'm passing to a module:

```
     1  // Test case for SO question on SystemVerilog array parameterization.
     2  //
     3  // Original author: David Banas <david@luminouscomputing.com>
     4  // Original date:   March 19, 2021
     5
     6  interface intf
     7    #( parameter ID = 0
     8     ) ();
     9
    10    logic data;
    11  endinterface
    12
    13  module foo
    14    #( parameter N_IFS = 1
    15     )( intf ifs[N_IFS]
    16      );
    17
    18    initial begin
    19      $display($sformatf("ID of last interface: %0d.", ifs[N_IFS-1].ID));
    20    end
    21  endmodule : foo
    22
    23  module top;
    24    localparam N_IFS = 2;
    25
    26    intf ifs[N_IFS]();
    27
    28    genvar i;
    29    generate
    30      for(i=0; i<N_IFS; i++)
    31        defparam ifs[i].ID = i;
    32    endgenerate
    33
    34    foo #(.N_IFS(N_IFS)) u_foo(.ifs(ifs));
    35  endmodule : top
```

And I'm getting this error from my *SystemVerilog* compiler:

```
Error-[SVDOGH] Invalid defparam on a parameter
/home/david/tmp/array_params.sv, 31
  Defparam on a parameter outside the generated hierarchy.
  Reference to 'ID' in defparam in instance 'top.ifs[0]' at
  /home/david/tmp/array_params.sv, 31 is invalid.
  Target parameter 'ID' must resolve in the generated hierarchy
  'top.genblk1[0]' starting at /home/david/tmp/array_params.sv, 30.
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to use is an *arrayed instance* of interface, which by itself is just another version of a *generate* block. If all element in the arrayed instance have the same parameter signatures, you can potentially use it as an array in a port connection. But, in this case you cannot modify their parameters. Arrayed instance requres use of certain types of ports which might be difficult to organize and manage. I have not seen use of this construct in practice.

Also 'defparam' is a obsolete construct and its use is discouraged. System verilog standard might depricate it in the future.

In your case you can use a much simpler construct to instantiate interfaces and connect every instance.

```
interface intf
   #( parameter ID = 0
    ) ();

   logic data;
 endinterface

 module foo
   #( parameter N_IFS = 1
    )( intf ifs);

   initial begin
     $display($sformatf("ID of last interface: %0d.", ifs.ID));
   end
 endmodule : foo

 module top;
   localparam N_IFS = 2;
   for(genvar i=0; i<N_IFS; i++) begin: loop
       intf #(.ID(i)) ifs();  // << instantiate with id
       foo u_foo(.ifs(ifs));  // << instantiat foo and connect to the interface instance
    end
 endmodule : top
```

In the above example interface is instantiated in a an array-like manned in the 'loop' with different IDs. The 'foo' module is instantiated in the same generate block and gets connected to the correct instance of the interface.

Comment: This is not entirely correct. You can have an array of interfaces, it's just that each instance go an array must have the same type. That is the definition of an array. If you try to give them unique parameterizations, they are no longer the same type.

Comment: @dave_59 As usual, you are correct :-), i updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks, @Serge! I think your proposed solution is valid when there is a 1:1 correspondence between the module "foo" and the interface "intf". Unfortunately, in my actual case I need my equivalent of "foo" to accept an array of intfs, and the size of that array to be parametrizable, so my code can be used in several different top-level projects.